# Can't check if keyboard is hidden in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-manifest, android-inputtype

I'm trying to check if a keyboard is visible. I wrote code and my code is working perfectly in Activity and some styles. This is my source

```
public class KeyboardVisibilityEvent {
private final static int KEYBOARD_VISIBLE_THRESHOLD_DP = 100;
public static void setEventListener(final Activity activity,
        final KeyboardVisibilityEventListener listener) {

    if (activity == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Parameter:activity must not be null");
    }

    if (listener == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Parameter:listener must not be null");
    }

    final View activityRoot = getActivityRoot(activity);

    final ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener =
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                private final Rect r = new Rect();

                private final int visibleThreshold = Math.round(
                        UIUtil.convertDpToPx(activity, KEYBOARD_VISIBLE_THRESHOLD_DP));

                private boolean wasOpened = false;

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    activityRoot.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int heightDiff = activityRoot.getRootView().getHeight() - r.height();

                    boolean isOpen = heightDiff > visibleThreshold;

                    if (isOpen == wasOpened) {
                        return;
                    }

                    wasOpened = isOpen;

                    listener.onVisibilityChanged(isOpen);
                }
            };
    activityRoot.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
    activity.getApplication()
            .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AutoActivityLifecycleCallback(activity) {
                @Override
                protected void onTargetActivityDestroyed() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        activityRoot.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
                    } else {
                        activityRoot.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(layoutListener);
                    }
                }
            });
}

public static boolean isKeyboardVisible(Activity activity) {
    Rect r = new Rect();

    View activityRoot = getActivityRoot(activity);
    int visibleThreshold =
            Math.round(UIUtil.convertDpToPx(activity, KEYBOARD_VISIBLE_THRESHOLD_DP));

    activityRoot.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = activityRoot.getRootView().getHeight() - r.height();

    return heightDiff > visibleThreshold;
}

private static View getActivityRoot(Activity activity) {
    return ((ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
  }
}

  KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(this, new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {

        }
    });
```

As I said this code is working perfectly, but now I want to use this code in Fragment. My Fragment's SoftInputMode is  SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING.

```
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

and in the Manifest source is

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is it possible to check keyboard's visibility when InputMode is adjustNothing?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: No as of now it is not possible. Note from the library: Please note that as described in this issue, https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent/issues/1 currently the library cannot detect visibility change when the activity's windowSoftInputMode do not change Activity's height(such as adjustNothing).

Comment: @AnuragSingh is right. it is not possible to check keyboard visibility using adjustNothing yet. because ViewTreeObserver can not observe until activity change its height when keyboard get appear or hide.